# RoR - Removing comma

Tags: ruby-on-rails

help me to write  rails code to remove comma for the below code

```
<%
student = []
student << "About Section:"
student << student_input(@input, :section_name)
student << student_input(@input, :section_strength)
%>
<%= student.join(", ") %>
```

I have output for this as "  **About Section:,** section name, section strength  "

I just want to remove the comma(,) following "About Section:,"

Comment: as this has been marked answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753933/ror-removing-comma , which is an exact duplicate / double post of this (first) one here, i vote for closing this original one.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like it'd be easier just to do this:

```
About Section: <%= student_input @input, :section_name %>, <%= student_input @input, :section_string %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go:

```
"#{student.shift} #{student.join(', ')"
```